# Show publisher actions only in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, chatter, publisher-action

I have a custom visualforce publisher action that is designed only for the Salesforce1 App. The problem with publisher actions is that those are shown both in Salesforce1 and the Chatter Feed. I want those actions to be visible only in Salesforce1.

It is posible to do that? and how you can achieve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is solved as of Summer15.

The page layout editor now has two places for actions--one for the feed, and another for the action bar.

[image: action bar layout]

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_actionbar_customization.htm

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time, sorry. 
Jody

Comment: bummer, I'll accept your answer until some comes up with a solution.